# Really bad wording and structure, help!

Tags: novel, structure

So, in the very first paragraph of my first chapter of my Work in progress novel, there's this absolute piece of trash event happening. And oh, my God I can't fix it for the life of me.

> In the year 3017 there was a large scale war- all countries against
>   America. The president wanted a dictatorship and changed laws, bending
>   them to his will. He wanted world domination and tried taking over
>   many smaller countries, some larger, Russia was top priority per
>   usual. Rallies broke out around the country, but the beginnings of
>   them started in the Capital. The leader of this rally was Greyson
>   Ammone, a strong willed man with a sharp intelligence. The war lasted around five years, give or take a few months.

Is there any way to strengthen this paragraph. There's just a little bit of history of why my novel takes place in this "post apocalyptic" type of world.

Can this be "morphed" into a better summary?

I have this long version, but no one would want to read *that*. I don't even want to. I am not asking for this to be edited, but can it be saved from being this butchered?

Ex. I was writing ideas for this intro down, and all of them were inevitably crossed out, but this one made it, somehow?
How can I express this "Destruction" idea be expressed without sounding like a middle-schooler?

Comment: In it's current form, this is asking what to write, which is off topic for us. I would recommend looking at the passage and trying to determine exactly what about it you feel is making it so bad. This is a great exercise at any time, and it will also help you narrow down what exactly you need help with. Make sure the question can apply to others, not just yourself, and it will be on topic.

Comment: *To be perfectly honest, I just want to know if this will sell or not.

Comment: I'll edit it in a bit.

Comment: Thomas Myron is right. This is a request for a rewrite which is off topic. Possibly you could turn it into a how do I express this idea question, though that is harder to do for fiction than for nonfiction. Until then, I am placing it on hold.

Comment: In it's current form, this is still a what to write...you are basically asking us if it can be saved, the answer is yes, anything can be saved. I can give you a hint to the problem though... you aren't really telling a story... you are mostly  recanting the story as if stating facts from a bullet point. It's like reading a history book. describe the war... reference the war at a later date but instead of giving a summary of the war, talk about a specific battle or event that happened and describe that.

Comment: ggiaquin is right, this is still off-topic. They key is to use your writing as *an example*. Your question should be, 'I have this writing, which suffers from problems A, B, and C. What can writers do to fix those problems?'

Comment: In the interest of help, without telling you what to write: Begin with your target. "Greyson Ammone led the victors of 3017, rocketing to the top of the rebel forces by dint of strategic brilliance and insights that seemed to manipulate his enemies into lethal mistakes. That included opposition within his own ranks. [break] The rebels were motivated by ..."

Comment: Do not begin with history, begin with CONFLICT that reveals history. The story of Greyson's fight for power and fight to unify disparate groups of rebels with various complaints, by finding a common ground they could agree to, giving up some goals for the assurance, by a guy that does not lose, that others will be accomplished. Whether Greyson succeeds or fails, if they believe in him at the time, they join him. But hint that there was a struggle for Greyson, his leadership was not automatic, and did not just happen for no reason. He led with ruthless brilliance, perhaps, like Napoleon.

Comment: @Amadeus the problem isn't also entirely that it is giving a history... it's also the way it's worded. It's boring... dry.... like he is listing off bullet points and putting them as consecutive sentences. I agree it's better to start with conflict, but in this case, he has a writing issue in itself with words and style.

Comment: @ggiaquin I think it is boring only because there is no apparent conflict. Once Aspen starts a struggle or puzzle or obstacle to overcome, refining that into actions and words is far easier. You are right, it is difficult to animate bullet points of facts. It is easier to show how facts get produced by choices, decisions and actions, especially if they seem to have some risk.

Comment: @Amadeus yes, In a chatroom here on the site, I took the liberty to re-write what he has above into something... more appeasing which he liked. I tried to sit down and discuss with him and break down what he liked about it and the differences from that and this, but I also had to head home from work and ran out of time. Hoping to continue that convo with him today. Unfortunately, this is a trend his writing has in general and not just with history sections (I have read a lot of his excerpts and his google doc novel). I feel bad... so hoping maybe I can help him in the right direction.